# Why is the Fitchburg Line Commuter Rail so slow between Porter and North Station?

Tags: trains, public-transport, boston, mbta

[North Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Station) in Boston, Massachusetts and [Porter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porter_station) in Cambridge, Massachusetts are two adjacent stations on the Fitchburg Line, a commuter rail line extending northwest from Boston.

The two stations are 3.4 miles apart. However, this trip takes 15 minutes inbound to Boston and 10 minutes outbound from Boston. That comes out to an average of 13.6 mph inbound and 20.4 mph outbound. Speaking from first-hand experience, the train often goes slower than this speed on sections of this track, going at a crawling pace.

It's quite frustrating being so close to the destination and moving so slowly. Why does the train move so slowly here?

Comment: Heh, I could've asked the same question for the Orange line between North Station and Community College. Perhaps [track repairs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwini8nridb-AhUz_7sIHTa5Af4QFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mbta.com%2Fschedules%2FOrange&usg=AOvVaw1SrUkna-PELWkTX47f1oZS)? (Though that site gives me a 403, maybe because I'm not in the USA anymore ...)

Comment: Why is US commuter rail so incompetent? That is basically your question... Mostly it is because the people running it are completely unaware what current best practices when it comes to passenger rail.

Comment: Is this specific to the Fitchburg line, or is it all MBTA and Amtrak trains being funnelled into a few tracks over the North Station drawbridge?  How often is the drawbridge opened for ship traffic?

Comment: @user4556274 I might be wrong, but I don't believe it's a drawbridge going into North Station; I think there is no ship traffic past that point. I believe there are four tracks going over the bridge. I've never been on any other service terminating at North Station, but the routes diverge very quickly, and it's not just the final merged bit that is slow.

Comment: It is absolutely a drawbridge. The cogeneration plant in Kendall Square reportedly used to take coal shipments by barge until the early 2000's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Speaking from first-hand experience, the train often goes slower than this speed on sections of this track, going at a crawling pace.
>
> It's quite frustrating being so close to the destination and moving so slowly. Why does the train move so slowly here?

Most of the line is straight, but the last mile is *absolutely bonkers*.

Entailing a bunch of tight curves where they pushed tracks around to fit a bunch of storage tracks next to the [Boston Engine Terminal (maintenance yard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBTA_Commuter_Rail_Maintenance_Facility).

Then a junction with the Rockport, Newburyport, Haverhill and Lowell lines.   Crossovers galore, as 13 tracks neck down to four for the ...

... [Bascule drawbridge over the Charles River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_River_Bridge_(Commuter_Rail)).  And *immediately* into

[image]

the fan-out at the station proper.  This isn't even a proper yard throat; there just isn't *space for that*. Look at the south side of the bridge, there isn't even a crossover there, so each of the two drawbridges serves half the terminal, and trains either enter or exit on the "wrong side". If they lose a bridge they lose half their tracks.  Really, the bulk of what could be laughably called a "yard throat" is on the north side of the drawbridge.  The single ladder track used by your line is obscured under the US-1 bridge. Fortunately the other lines have another half mile to get sorted, but wow.  That is a lot of track work in not a lot of space.

And to answer your question about "why so slow", all the switches are #8 (15 MPH) - they don't have the physical space for #20 (40 MPH) crossovers. And with the yard throat so *spread out* because of the drawbridge, yeah, you're going most of a mile *with some part of your train" on top of a 10-15 MPH switch.

Also, all these switches are signaled, which means a dispatcher has to talk to the train and work controls to get the track switches thrown over and the proper signal given.  When they're at walking speed, they're crawling up on a red signal waiting for the switch to throw and get their green.

**Hell of a place to put a train station.**

So yeah, I know it's fashionable in Boston to paint the MBTA like a bunch of klutzes that can't punch their way out of a paper bag, but I can't honestly say Metra, Caltrain or GO/Toronto would do much better with those constraints.  And really, yards like Chicago Union Station aren't fantastically better.  The only people who really have it dialed in is Philadelphia - imagine the moment you reach the bridge you pick up speed and make normal stops again - North Station, City Hall, South Station and onward to Kingston, because most inbound lines *run through* to become outbound lines, dispensing with terminal nonsense. That's Philly.

And that bridge is a bottleneck, but mainly because there are 4 tracks not 8.  (*Because there **was***, but somebody really wanted a few grand of scrap steel).

> However, this trip takes 15 minutes inbound to Boston and 10 minutes outbound to Boston.

That's a different thing. That's called "padding". Think about how train schedules work. If the train publishes a schedule, it can't leave the station *early* or it will leave people behind.  However, that doesn't apply at *the last station*; they can certainly arrive early there, so that's the only place you can "pad" the schedule.  By calling it 15 minutes instead of 10, that means if they are up to 5 minutes late, that counts as "not late".

Is it honest? Well, I don't know. What if they *are* on time but are delayed 4 minutes in the congested yard throat by late trains from Haverhill and Newburyport.  Is it the crew's fault? No.

Comment: I find this explanation rather amazing. Looking at openrailwaymap the approach does not appear especially curvy or complicated. And the remark on how the switches are signalled means that the dispatcher has to "work the controls" and talk to the train crew: Well, a modern interlocking (as in, post WW2) does all that pretty much automatically.

Comment: @Krist You'd be amazed how slow railroads replace plant... I've actually operated an Armstrong interlocking on a live mainline in the 90s. The problem is, if trains are stacked up coming in, the plant has to be re-lined for each train and you don't know the arrival sequence until they're near, because delays happen. Yes, they have modern kit that'll let you pre-stage a series of clearances, but it's costly, adds complexity/failure points, and its real value is letting fewer dispatchers manage more route. Well, they need one (1) yard dispatcher, and you can't improve on that number.

Comment: Actually on most passenger railways interlocking is done automatically nowadays. Even on the small local railway serving our village the whole process of routing is set by a computer, and the only thing the conductor needs to do is signal that a train is ready to leave. The computer does the rest.

Answer (score 5):

There are probably a few factors.

1. Track design

The trains and most of the tracks are designed for an operational speed of 60m/h. However that's less the case in the densely populated cities. The tracks are old, have lots of switches close the main stations, frequent crossing with other traffic etc. It's not just North Stations: all trains in and out of South station are also excruciating slow close to the station.

North Station seems to be particularly bad not just for trains but for the subway as well. The green line crosses the river on the museum's bridge. There is an actual stop sign when it goes underground again at North Station, the posted speed limit is 3m/h (yes, that's THREE) and it's famous for it's screeching noise when going through the right turns at this spot.

2. Intentional mismanagement

A few years ago the Boston MBTA had the worst on-time record of all commuter rail systems in the US (which is already a low bar). At the time the governor yelled at them to fix it (threating reduced funding). Instead of improving the operational efficiency, they simply padded the schedules and increased the nominal ravel time. For example, the express lines from Worcester have a fairly long stretch without any stops (West Natick to Landsdowne). In normal conditions it's hard for them to go as slow as the schedule is planned so they have to stop somewhere in the middle to run down the clock. The choice of location appears to be up the engineer. On the inbound it's often the golf course in Weston and on the outbound it's Lake Cochichuate, both being the most scenic spots on the route.

Boston has outsourced the management of the Commuter Rail to French company called Keolis. Keolis has performed poorly and in 2017 the state decided to not renew their contract which even more lowered Keolis' motivation. Spooked by the pandemic, the state reversed that decision in 2020, so Keolis is sill mismanaging the trains.

The sheet amount of incompetence and not caring at all is hard to understate. A simple example: in Framingham the trains often arrive in the "wrong" track and there is no signage or indication for it. If you are waiting on the inbound side for an inbound train that happens to randomly arrive on the outbound side,  you will miss the train. It takes a while to get to the other side and they won't wait. As a result, most people have taken to waiting ON THE BRIDGE that crosses the platforms as it's the midpoint between the two possible embarkation spots. It's still a mad scramble but at least you have a good chance of making it. Unless, of course, you are elderly, injured, disabled, have luggage, or have slightly limited mobility, in which case you are sheer out of luck,

Comment: It used to be that the Framingham/Worcester line was left-running between Boston and Framingham during PM peak so that the outbound trains could stop at the single-platform stations in Newton. That was predictable enough, though I admit they could have had better signage at the stations. I don't know if that's still what they're doing though.